# Javascript in Opera strange math operations

Tags: javascript, opera

i have js cript

```
var lf = -10;
if(lf < 0 )
$("element").setStyle({left:(parseInt(lf)+10)+'px'});
```

this lot very strange

```
(parseInt(lf)+10) = - 20;
```

in opera

Version
10.62

Build
6438

Platform
Linux

System
x86_64, 2.6.31-22-generic

in all another browser (parseInt(lf)+10) = 0;

How it can be ?

---

Problem not solved this full code function it runing when mouseover in div with interval 10ms
it using prototype
in all another browsers work fine but not on opera ((

```
function openMenu(){
                var pleft = $("slidemenubar2").getStyle("left");

                if(parseInt(pleft) < 0){
                    $("slidemenubar2").setStyle({left: (parseInt(pleft)+10)+'px'});
                    alert($("slidemenubar2").getStyle("left"));//always <0
                }
            }
```

how it can be ?( don't anderstand.

Comment: Do you have a page with this problem online somewhere?